# Prove Cauchy's estimate for analytic functions using power series representation

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

As is known, Cauchy's estimate states that for a function $f$ that's analytic in a disk $B_R$ and bounded by the inequality $|f(z)|< M$ for all $z$ in $B_R$, then the n-th derivtive can be estimated as $$|f^{(n)}(0)|\leq \frac{n!M}{R^n}$$
For $z$ on a circle centered at $0$ with radius $r<R$ the estimate can be written as
$$|f^{(n)}(z)|<\frac{n!M}{(R-r)^n}$$
All proofs I have seen for this estimate use the representations of the coefficients in the power series of $f$ which are given by contour integrals. However, I was wondering if it's possible to get the same result (at least for the first derivative) by direct calculations using the power series.
My approach was the following:
Since $f$ is bounded by $M$, I know that for $f(z) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} f_kz^k$ the coefficients can be estimated as $|f_k| < M R^{-k}$ on $B_R$. The derivative is given by $f'(z) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} k f_k z^{k-1}$, so if I take $z$ to be on a smaller circle, I get the estimate
$$|f'(z)|\leq\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}k|f_k||z|^{k-1}<M\sum_{k= 0}^{\infty}k R^{-k}r^{k-1} = \frac{M}{R}\frac{1}{(1-r/R)^2} = \frac{MR}{(R-r)^2}$$
I don't know if there is a better way to do it like this, because this estimate is more or less of the form that I want, but not accurate enough.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: There is a clever proof: let $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k$ and $\omega$ be a primitive $n$-th root of unity. Then $F(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(\omega^kz)/n$ is a power series in the form of $a_nz^n+\sum_{k>n}b_kz^k$. Hence $g(z)=F(z)/z^n$ is analytic in $B_R$. Now apply the maximum modulus principle to complete the proof.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! But why is $F(z)$ a power series starting at $z^n$? If I choose $n = 2$, I'd have $\omega = -1$, so $F(z)$ would have the form $F(z) = f(\omega^0 z)/2+f(\omega z)/2 = f(z)/2 +f(-z)/2 = 1/2*(a_0+a_1 z+a_2 z^2+.... +a_0-a_1z +a_2 z^2\mp...) = 1/2(2a_0+a_2z^2+...)$ or am I missing something?

Comment: to clarify on @user1551 's comment -- that approach works as a natural generalization of Schwarz's Lemma -- but like Schwarz it requires $f(0)=0$.  It is the basic case OP should try to first understand.  Then the more general result comes from an alternating sum of 2nth roots of unity (with $\omega$ as the standard generator).  I.e. considering $F(z)=\frac{1}{2n} \sum_{k=0}^{2n-1} (-1)^k f(z\omega^k)$ .  Texts taking the Weierstrass approach to Complex Analysis should walk you through this.

Comment: My bad. I have unconsciously assumed that $f(0)=0$. As user8675309 has pointed out, in the general case one should instead consider $F(z)=\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}(-1)^kf(\omega^kz)$ where $\omega$ is a primitive $2n$-th root of unity. Since $1+(-\omega^k)+(-\omega^k)^2+\cdots+(-\omega^k)^{2n-1}$ is equal to zero when $0\le k<n$ and equal to $2n$ when $k=n$, we see that $F(z)$ is in the form of $a_nz^n+\sum_{k>n}b_kz^k$.